# I'm trying to create a column in a pandas dataframe of ordered categorical dtype (in a Jupyter notebook) but it's not ordered

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I'm trying to create an ordered Categorical DType column in an existing pandas dataframe, based on an existing column of dtype categorical. I'm running pandas 0.25.3

I've run the following code

```
print(ri.stop_length.head())
cats = ri['stop_length'].unique()
print(cats)
cattype = CategoricalDtype(categories=cats, ordered=True)

ri['stop_length'] = ri.stop_length.astype('category', cattype)
print(ri.stop_length.cat.ordered)
print(ri.stop_length.head())
```

which gives me the following output

```
stop_datetime
2005-01-04 12:55:00     short
2005-01-23 23:15:00     short
2005-02-17 04:15:00     short
2005-02-20 17:15:00    medium
2005-02-24 01:20:00     short
Name: stop_length, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [short, medium, long]
[short, medium, long]
Categories (3, object): [short, medium, long]
False
stop_datetime
2005-01-04 12:55:00     short
2005-01-23 23:15:00     short
2005-02-17 04:15:00     short
2005-02-20 17:15:00    medium
2005-02-24 01:20:00     short
Name: stop_length, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [short, medium, long]
```

Why isn't the resulting categorical dtype ordered?

To check, I've run

```
ri[ri.stop_length > 'short'].shape
```

which returns the following error

> TypeError: Unordered Categoricals can only compare equality or not